# why pop over display all time in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I make a pop over using directive .But my popover display all time when i generate row dynamically .I need to show popover or tool only on  icon click ?

Now it is display without click and also display oll rows .i want to display only that row which is clicked?

Here is plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/OYiawflIBnpJ1PKx02LG?p=preview

```
app.directive('popUpCheck', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'pop.html',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.label = attrs.popoverLabel;
            $(el).popover({
                trigger: 'click',
                html: true,
                placement: 'right'
            });
        }
  }
});
```

Here is my html

```
<table ng-table class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="guitar in guitarVariable" style="border: 5px solid #000000; background: pink" >
    <td><span pop-up-check class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" popUpCheck></span> </td>

        <td data-title="'Name'">{{guitar.color}}</td>


        <td data-title="'class'">{{guitar.value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: please check my plunker I will update my Question

Answer (score 0):

From the console your first problem is that there is no jquery and bootstrap-ui doesn't use jquery. So calling `$(el).popover` is never going to work.

I'd recommend looking at the docs for bootstrap-ui popover here http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover. If you need the custom wrapper then there should be docs somewhere on the site for using it from javascript.

Comment: Thanks for giving answer and you please change my plunker.so that I will understand much better

Comment: Sorry I can't do that, I'm not too familiar with bootstrap-ui's workings. From what I can see it's considerably more complex under the hood than AngularStrap which is what I use.